# Windows Azure create table everyday

Tags: c#, .net, azure, logging

I'm using Azure Storage to keep my logs (table 'LOGS'), but logs amount grows, so I want to create table per one day to remove old logs. Also I want to remove old logs in easy way (as far I I know there is no opportunity to remove item by partition key).

My question is: How can I programically create new storage table everyday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your scenario where you want logging data for a day to go in a separate table, there are many ways you can go about it.

- **Create table on demand**: In this approach, you essentially check if the table for that day doesn't exist you create it just before you insert log data. However this is not recommended because you will be performing this task every time you want to write some log data though this is the most fool-proof way.
- **Create tables in advance**: In this approach, you essentially create tables for coming days (say 5) in advance. For example, see the code below:

  ```
      var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
      var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
      var currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
          var tableName = string.Format("Logs{0}", currentDate.AddDays(i).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
          var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
          table.CreateIfNotExists();
      }
  ```

Now what you can do is create a `WebJob` with this code and make it run everyday at `1 second after midnight`. So everyday you're creating a logs table for next 5 days.

> Also I want to remove old logs in easy way (as far I I know there is
>   no opportunity to remove item by partition key).

With this approach of keeping separate table for each day, deleting becomes easier. You simply delete the table and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this nice arcticle written by Tamra Myers would help?
https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/